# How to execute code from database in Django

Tags: django, templates

I created a blog with Django and my model post is like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    content = RichTextField()
    # ...
```

In my template, I display the content of posts like this: `{{ post.content|safe }}`

What I want is to execute code that is in the content of the post. Let say I want to add a link to the "about me" page, so logically I would add this in the content of the post:

```
# some text here

<a href="{% url 'about' %}">about me</a>

# another text here
```

This doesn't work. if I hover the URL I can see the URL `127.0.0.1:8000/post/21/{% url 'about' %}`.
How can I do that.

**Edit**

Actually, to redirect to the `about me` page I can simply do `<a href="/about/">about me</a>`

But what if I want to redirect to another post? I have to specify the id or the slug of the post but I can't do:

```
<a href="{% url 'core:post' post.id %}">post</a>
```

Comment: Show your template and your view + your urls.py

Answer (score 0):

"|safe" filter renders only html code.

To render django template from db you should use render or render_to_string in your view. But note that this is an extremely insecure practice cause to many contexts are available to get and execute in django template language

Comment: I did it without the `safe` filter and it didn't work!